# Getting into a mathematics master's program from engineering?

Tags: mathematics, changing-fields, engineering

I'm sorry if the question is not of the kind usually dealt with in the website. Honestly, I'm looking for a personal advice and/or real-world experience to help me figure what should I do.

**My question is** whether applying for a master's program is a good idea? or not? Given that I have no deep knowledge in mathematics, except for some engineering level linear algebra and calculus.

**More details about me:** I'm an electrical engineering (EE) graduate with a B.Sc. and a M.Sc. in power engineering. Although I finished my degrees with high grades and a strong resume, I didn't ever feel a thing for EE to be motivated enough to go after it in my professional life. On the other side, I always enjoyed math both in high school and college, and by "enjoying" math I'm not just talking about ordinary problem solving but mathematical stuff including defining mathematical objects, theorems, proofs and so on.

For me, the good thing about mathematics is that I always felt an aptitude for it. I get it naturally and in a joyful way. In many cases, at first sight, I feel the solution or how to get that, in a strange abstract way. During my entire education, I have always had a closer connection with my mathematics teachers/lecturers. The problem in college was that the level and depth of mathematics courses in engineering programs (even EE) was too little to feel satisfaction. Therefore, I am considering pursuing mathematics itself.

Comment: I haven't heard any negatives so far.  Perhaps you would find it reassuring to hear that plenty of people move from using math for science or engineering into working more deeply with math itself.  I suggest you speak and email with some math professors and graduate advisors.  Also, start looking at some math programs of study and course descriptions.

Comment: What do you want to do with the Math degree?  If you are motivated to do that and get the degree, you should be fine.  As aparente001 stated, plenty of people do that.

Comment: I don't consider this question off-topic because it is about how someone with inferior preparation and superior motivation is likely to do in a graduate program. I provided an answer from my own personal observation.

Answer (score 3):

"Force = Mass * Acceleration."

You appear to be worried about your inferior "mass." What you may not realize is that you have superior "acceleration" to compensate, probably bringing up your "force" level to at least average.

I entered a math-oriented PhD program with someone who had only one year of calculus, but whose "acceleration" you remind me of. Within a year, he equalized in "mass." Then his superior "acceleration" took him to the top of the class.

The same could happen to you, if you have the natural gifts and "bent" that you say you have. Your engineering gives you enough "background" to get in the game.

Comment: I agree with the response. For future students which want to change the directions of study it would be good to change the path sooner during the MSc. I know three people which changed successfully the direction, but from engineering/computer science to theoretical physics and applied physics.

Comment: What does "math-oriented PhD program" mean?  Was this a degree in mathematics itself?  My opinion would be that someone with only a year of calculus would be extremely underprepared to enter a graduate program in mathematics, and likely wouldn't be accepted.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It was a program in Mathematical Economics at CMU (now Tepper School). We had to take Probability, Statistics I and II, Real Analysis,  Optimization, and Advanced Calculus, the first year. The other person survived the program. I did not, even with the equivalent of a minor in Math. He did have some statistics courses plus calculus, which may be how he got in. But he was a star, once he did.

Comment: Ok.  I am not convinced that this is comparable.  Masters programs in mathematics would generally have a *major* in mathematics, including most of those courses (and more), as a prerequisite for entrance, and start immediately with courses that build upon them.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I had the opposite problem. I had "ten" math courses, but repeated four out of six. And my "acceleration" was poor because I took everything "twice." This guy seems to have found his true math calling, and has a "related" background in engineering.. We hear stories of teenaged immigrant children entering middle or high school with little English and catching up to their age level in one year. Sometimes natural ability trumps preparation.

Comment: That's all well and good, but preparation is easy to demonstrate to a graduate admission committee (with a transcript) and "natural ability" is hard (many are skeptical that any such thing exists).  And faculty will have had many experiences of students who fail out of graduate programs due to under-preparation.